# Creating a folder in the root of a drive using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, root

Trying to make a very simple batch file which allows the user to create and name a folder on the root of a drive and copy some files from some other place. Literally all I've done so far is:

MD F:\%

I keep getting access denied errors. I originally tried this on my C Drive, and when I got the error I assumed it was some weird permissions thing and tried it on my second drive and got the same error, and then my external drive and got the same error. I double checked to make sure I have full admin rights to my PC, and I do, so I'm guessing there is a different way to write the batch file than what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

This is what icacls show

```
C:\Windows\system32>icacls c:
c: NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
   NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
   BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
   BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
   CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
   APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

So users and unelevated admins can't write to the root drive. Run your script as admin.

Comment: I run the command line as an administrator, and I still get the error message. Or do you mean just right click the batch file and run as an admin? In this file I want the user to name the folder that is being created, so I need it to work from command line

Comment: You have to right click and choose _Run As Administrator_ or choose somewhere else for the folder. `BUILTIN\Users:(RX)` Read and Execute only.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. I keep just writing % instead of %1

Comment: % is a legal name.